# How do I see the invocations caused by running cmake-generated makefiles?

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

How do I see the g++ invocations caused by running make?  I am generating my makefile using cmake, so it is quite large.

Using verbose=1, cmake is still hiding the g++ invocations:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object ui/CMakeFiles/ui.dir/mainwindow.cc.o
In file included from /Users/neil/nn/src/ui/mainwindow.h:6,
                 from /Users/neil/nn/src/ui/mainwindow.cc:9:
/Users/neil/nn/src/./core/globals.h:8:26: error: glog/logging.h: No such file or directory
```

I want to see if it's passing the right include directors to g++ because it's not finding glog/logging.h

Comment: Are you sure you use make without a wrapper or whatever? Try `which make` and `unalias make`.

Comment: I think cmake generates a makefile that invokes g++ through some kind of wrapper, so your intuition is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peek in the `CMakeFiles/ui.dir/` directory; you'll probably be interested in the `flags.make` file, though the non-includes portion of the `g++` invocation is stored in `build.make`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`make VERBOSE=TRUE`

Comment: is your makefile generated with cmake?

Comment: Yes it is generated using cmake on a Ubuntu distrib.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the verbosity level with `make VERBOSE=""` ([source](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Is_there_an_option_to_produce_more_.27verbose.27_compiling.3F)).

Answer (score 0):

Run CMake with -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE="ON"

There is still a lot of noise though, so you may need to dump stdout & stderr to a file and grep for the name of the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

From the shell prompt:

```
VERBOSE=1 make
```

(that is, run `make` with `VERBOSE` environment variable set to `1`).